# SPI multi-slave using individualized MOSI requests for chip selection

Tags: spi

I would like to create an SPI bus with multiple slaves connected to the MOSI and MISO lines (not daisy-chained). The slaves would be microcontrollers reporting data to the central master microcontroller.

As many others do, I would like to avoid the additional chip select line for each slave. As far as I understand, usually, this is not possible due to the predefined behavior of the slaves where any message from the master would trigger a response from all slaves simultaneously (were they all chip-selected).

I was thinking that, as I control the behavior of the slaves, I could assign unique IDs to them and make them wait (in Rx-only mode) for an individualized request from the master. After receiving a request, the respective slave would switch to Tx mode and respond upon the next clock burst, then return to Rx-only mode. All slaves would be locally chip-selected all the time.

Can someone advise me against this? Am I missing something? I was not able to find any discussion on this setup.

Comment: It should work if you can manually control the MISO output of SPI slaves in software, which depends on your MCU capabilities. But would it not be better to have a separate chip select? Or daisy chain with single chip select? How many slaves? Should you consider using something else than SPI?

Comment: @Justme, regarding using something else, I guess what I described is very similar to I2C. I was leaning towards SPI as I need the units to be on separate boards (approximately 2m apart) and I got the impression that SPI would be a bit more suited electrically to perform in this layout.

Comment: Well, 2m for SPI may not be very good idea, it might be hard to make it work, harder than 2m for I2C. But it really depends on what your bus topology is and how many devices there are and what speed you intend to communicate.

Comment: @Justme, I was actually considering passing the SPI as a differential signal through a twisted pair (using LVDS amps maybe?). I think that would be less straightforward in case of I2C? On the other hand, it feels a bit overkill to use differential signal for just a couple of meters if I2C would be doable without additional circuitry.

Comment: But if you use LVDS drivers for SPI, how many LVDS receivers can one driver drive? And then the control of MISO becomes irrelevant, you would need to control the transmit enable of LVDS driver, if it has one. And standard LVDS can't have drivers in the middle of a bus, only at end of a bus, and termination must be at end too. Maybe BLVDS or MLVDS solves it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into these questions.

Comment: Daisy-chain in serial. Make it so that the microcontroller behaves as a shift register until CS is released. I controlled a bunch of motor drivers this way.